# Are checked events firing "late" or "early"?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, telerik

I am using a Checkbox control inside an ItemTemplate of a Telerik RadJumpList.
The ItemTemplate is defined like this:

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                    Margin="4">

            <Image Source="/Assets/Weather.png"
                   Width="64"
                   Height="64"
                   Margin="0,4,12,4" Stretch="Fill" />

            <CheckBox x:Name="checkBox"
                      IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}"
                      Checked="checkBox_CheckedChanged"
                      Unchecked="checkBox_CheckedChanged" />

            <TextBlock FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeExtraLarge}"
                       FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyLight}"
                       Text="{Binding Name}"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
```

The JumpList is defined like this:

```
        <telerikDataControls:RadJumpList Grid.Row="1"
                                         x:Name="FavoriteJumpList"
                                         ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemTemplate}"
                                         GroupHeaderTemplate="{StaticResource GroupHeaderTemplate}"
                                         StickyHeaderTemplate="{StaticResource StickyHeaderTemplate}"
                                         GroupPickerItemsPanel="{StaticResource ItemsPanelTemplate}"
                                         ItemTap="FavoriteJumpList_ItemTap">

            <telerikDataControls:RadJumpList.GroupPickerItemTemplateSelector>
                <local:PhoneBookTemplateSelector x:Name="TemplateSelector"
                                                 EmptyItemTemplate="{StaticResource EmptyItemTemplate}"
                                                 LinkedItemTemplate="{StaticResource LinkedItemTemplate}" />
            </telerikDataControls:RadJumpList.GroupPickerItemTemplateSelector>

        </telerikDataControls:RadJumpList>
```

The event handler is defined like this:

```
        private void checkBox_CheckedChanged( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e )
        {
        var count = _app.AppData.Favorites.FavoritePoints.Count( favorite => favorite.IsChecked );
        WriteLine( "Count {0}", count );
        }
```

In the c# of the page, the JumpList is initialized like this:

```
        FavoriteJumpList.IsAsyncBalanceEnabled = true;
        FavoriteJumpList.IsStickyHeaderEnabled = true;
        FavoriteJumpList.GroupCheckMode = GroupCheckMode.None;
        FavoriteJumpList.ItemCheckedStateChanged += FavoriteJumpList_ItemCheckedStateChanged;

        // add custom group picker items, including all alphabetic characters
        var groupPickerItems = new List<string>( 32 );
        foreach ( var c in Alphabet )
            {
            groupPickerItems.Add( new string( c, 1 ) );
            }
        FavoriteJumpList.GroupPickerItemsSource = groupPickerItems;

        // add the group and sort descriptors
        var groupByFirstName = new GenericGroupDescriptor<FavoriteLocation, string>( favoriteLocation => favoriteLocation.Name.Substring( 0, 1 ).ToLower() );
        FavoriteJumpList.GroupDescriptors.Add( groupByFirstName );

        var sort = new GenericSortDescriptor<FavoriteLocation, string>( favoriteLocation => favoriteLocation.Name );
        FavoriteJumpList.SortDescriptors.Add( sort );

        // assign data source
        LoadFavorites();

        FavoriteJumpList.ItemsSource = _app.AppData.Favorites.FavoritePoints;
```

I put two break points. One in checkBox_CheckedChanged on the line:

```
WriteLine( "Count {0}", count );
```

and one on the line RaisePropertyChanged:

```
    private bool _isChecked;
    [DataMember]
    public bool IsChecked
        {
        get
            {
            return _isChecked;
            }
        set
            {
            _isChecked = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged( "IsChecked" );
            }
        }
```

Both breakpoints are triggered. However, I get the breakpoint

```
checkBox_CheckedChanged()
```

being triggered **BEFORE** the

```
RaisePropertyChanged( "IsChecked" );
```

is triggered, which is unacceptable (and unexpected as well). 
The count variable in

```
checkBox_CheckedChanged()
```

is used to Enable/Disable Toolbar buttons, and the count is lagging in time and shows wrong value.

Any Idea why the wrong order of events (or delay) is triggering here, and how can I handle it correctly?

Thx

Comment: That isn't wrong though. As soon as the checkbox value no longer equals its current value the changed event is fired. This logically happens BEFORE the checked property assignment.

Comment: So how would I detect an event after the Variable IsChecked has already being set to the correct value?

Comment: Your title doesn't match your question, are the checked events firing "late" or "early"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MJW's answer is correct. However in order to solve my problem I was modified the code such that the count calculation is done when the CheckBox click event was triggerd.

It works in my private case but I am not sure if it is a rule that the click event is fired after the data is already updated (i.e. the binding is already done).

Thx.